# Найти радиус наименьшего круга (с центром в начала координат), внутрь которого попадают все ЭТИ точки

Tags: visual-c++

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdio>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;
int main() {
double x1, x2,r,y1, y2;
cin >> x1, x2,y1,y2);
r = sqrt(pow(x2 - x1, 2) + pow(y2 - y1, 2));
cout << r;
}
```

И выдает ошибку [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Наверное потому, что в коде есть больше, чем нужно

```
int main() {
    double x1, x2,r,y1, y2;
    cin >> x1, x2,y1,y2); // ОЙ ЧТО ТУТ ЗА ТАКОЕ
    r = sqrt(pow(x2 - x1, 2) + pow(y2 - y1, 2));
    cout << r;
}
```

вам же компилятор на конкретную строку наверное еще и ругается?

**P.S.**

и кстати задача неправильно решена

вы рассчитали расстояние между точками, а не то, что требовалось в условии